# How to open Google Chrome from an Android Application?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile

i want to open google chrome from my android application. when chrome opens the display area, address bar, buttons, etc should be visible but the the tabs must become invisible or an application name or image must be placed on top of the tab. the user should not get the feeling that chrome web browser is being used. i want to publish the application in google play.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the information for [Android Webapps](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/overview.html), you have two choices - run your app in the browser or via webviews.

Have a look at [Android Webviews](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) and [the Webview api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Your users will not feel that chrome is being used.  There's no address bar and you have to [add navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation) if you need it

Comment: the the loading time of pages is very long. and all features of the page cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this to load Chrome and have the controls removed.  Chrome is also not part of the WebView on Android.

The closet you can get is to load Chrome as a page and then force full screen mode via the scrollTo(0,1) method and then on first touch call webkitRequestFullscreen on the document... however once the user breaks out of full-screen they will see the normal browser UI.

If you really want, you could embed ContentShell, however this adds 30+MB to your package size and it also is insanely hard to do just for a simple app.